How to customize X11 font cursor
According to the documentation of XCreateFontCursor:

Applications are encouraged to use this interface for their cursors because the font can be customized for the individual display type.

How do I actually customize the cursor generated from this method?
I've tried setting XCURSOR_SIZE environment variable to no percieved effect, I've tried setting XCursor.theme: redglass in my Xresources and this changes some applications but not all, (interestingly emacs uses the selected theme in the editor area but not in the menu bars) and as I am using dwm as my window manager no configuration specific to a desktop environment is applicable.

What are you trying to do ("customize") specifically? Just change the cursor size? Different X applications use different GUI libraries and different methods (and levels) of UI customization. Related Arch wiki article: Cursor themes, also e.g. Cursor size or theme does not change on Plasma (Wayland).

I want my window manager dwm which defines its cursors using XCreateFontCursor to have a larger cursor. GUI libraries doesn't matter here it is just using core X11 library calls. I'd like to apply customisation to that.

and several apps inherit the cursor from dwm such as the emacs menu bars as I stated in the question.

For XCURSOR_SIZE and the corresponding Xcursor.size (note: lowercase "C", also Xcursor.theme, see Xcursor(3)) to take effect, the cursor theme has to support the given size. Xcursor also depends on Xft.dpi setting if it doesn't find neither the environment variable nor the resource.
